# How to copy rows without duplicating primary keys

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently in my Database i have 3 tables; `foo`, `bar` and `quazo`. Im attempting to copy rows from `foo` into `quazo`, but i keep hitting error

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '119ab9d171cce2528d9ac95541915d546304bfe59fcb3f1492d7cc8db3e0c285' for key 'PRIMARY'. I know its because this entry is a primary Key and is already in quazo
```

My current SQL statement is this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO quazo(deviceID) SELECT deviceID FROM foo WHERE yeargroup=12)
```

I essentially need to write a statement that will copy the needed fields from foo, and ignore duplicate primary keys to stop this `error` from happening. Also, i need this statement to read data from a table, and a PHP POST variable and insert it into `quazo`. I was thining something like this, but it produces an error:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO quazo(deviceID, jobID) VALUES(SELECT deviceID FROM foo WHERE yeargroup=12, '$jobID')"))
```

Would this seconds statement be achieved via a join? If so, how?

Thanks for your help and sorry for the noob question! Havent done `SQL` in a long time

Comment: "*ignore duplicate primary keys to stop this error from happening*"—do you mean that you want to ignore (i.e. discard) records in `foo` for which the PK already exists in `quazo`, that you want to ignore the error and overwrite the data in `quazo`, or that you want to insert the record with a new PK?

Comment: Please provide your full table definitions and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: How about `INSERT INTO scans(deviceID, jobID) SELECT deviceID, '$jobID' FROM students WHERE yeargroup=12`?

Comment: MySQL has the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` formulation to do something like what you want.  Without knowing your table definitions it's hard to offer more specific advice.

Comment: Btw, instead of `foo` and `quazo` I can only see `students` and `scans` in your SQL.

Comment: Sorry guys updated/edited the OP. And im essentially trying to copy across data to quazo - however, if foo's primary key already exists in quazo, then ignore copying that record.